# DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have been facing this problem when I am trying to put a file in hdfs from local system. Below I have pasted the error

```
15/04/06 15:26:01 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception  for block BP-828097856-192.168.2.80-1424273979398:blk_1073752341_11540
java.io.IOException: Bad response ERROR for block BP-828097856-192.168.2.80-1424273979398:blk_1073752341_11540 from datanode 192.168.2.82:50010
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:897)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing hadoop fsck / -blocks -locations -files to clear up any lost blocks.

Comment: All the blocks are fine. The problem comes when the file is sending from local file system to hdfs

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your cluster healthy status with: `hdfs dfsadmin -report`, pay attention to the Capacity, DFS Used, DFS Remaining properties.
Then, check the disk on datanode `192.168.2.82` to see whether the disk is full or having some bad sectors.
From the [exception](https://marc.info/?l=flume-user&m=137619893026085&w=2) it's pretty clear that you're experiencing error relating to [datanode's disk](http://onlyricks.blogspot.com/2012/10/hadoop-common-errors-with-possible.html).